# Use one Macro in another Macro

Tags: macros, notepad++

I want to make a macro in Notepad++ that will essentially use another macro, is there a way to do this?

Basically the keystrokes would go like so:

`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`Home` - Select everything from cursor to the beginning of the file

`ALT`+`H` - Hide the selected lines

Then another macro doing the reverse.  The issue is that `ALT`+`H` is already a Macro under the Main Menu tab (Row 117 "Hide Lines").  When I try to record the macro, it just highlights the text.

This would effectively block off a specific area of code to work with.  The final result would hopefully be similar to [KEDIT's selective editing](http://www.kedit.com/features.ia1.html)

```
Selective Line Editing

This is one of KEDIT's most popular features. The selective editing facility
lets you focus on a subset of the lines in a file, such as all lines containing
a particular string. You can have KEDIT display only this subset of your file,
and you can perform editing operations that affect only this subset. You can
then return to viewing and working with the entire file, with the lines in the
selected subset (as modified by your editing) remaining in their original
position in the file.
```

Once the lines are hidden I can make custom Search and Replace Macros that only select un-hidden lines (`CTRL`+`Home` -> `Down` -> `Down` -> `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`End` -> `SHIFT`+`Up` -> `SHIFT`+`Up`)

**NOTE**:  If there is some way that I can limit Search and Replace to only do *visible* lines then that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use a program like [Auto HotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) that can send keystrokes to the program.  Use the script below to create hotkeys for hiding blocks:

```
^'::
Send {Up 1}
Send ^+{Home}
Send !h
Send {Down 1}
return

!'::
Send {Down 1}
Send ^+{End}
Send !h
Send {Up 1}
return
```

The upper block binds `CTRL+'` to hide lines above the cursor, the bottom block binds `ALT+'` to hide lines below the cursor.

On a side note, the line the curser was on will be either 2nd or 2nd to last (depending on if you hid the lines above or below).  So to select the "non-hidden" lines you can use the keystrokes below in a macro.

`CTRL+Home` -> `Down` -> `CTRL+SHIFT+End` -> `SHIFT+Up`